# Enable/disable virtual keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a [virtual keyboard](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/). I have a checkbox that controls whether the virtual keyboard is displayed or not. The thing is that I don't understand how to disable it. I try to unbind it but it doesn't work...

I also tried to use namespaces and then unbind all namespaces but still the keyboard remains accessible after a click on the text box.

```
<input class="virtualKeyboardField ui-keyboard-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-val="true" data-val-required="The User name field is required." id="loginUserName" name="UserName" type="text" value="" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    //show login
    $("#showLogin").on({
      click: function () {
        $("#loginFormDiv").toggle("slow");
      }
    });
    $("#cb_showVKey").on('click', CheckIsToShowKey);
  });
  function CheckIsToShowKey(event) {
    //var isCheck = $("#cb_showVKey").is(':checked');
    //alert("ischecked? " + isCheck);
    if ($("#cb_showVKey").is(':checked')) {
      //if checked
      BindKeyboards();
    } else {
      //not checked
      UnBindKeyboards();
    }
  }
  function bindVirtualKeyboards() {
    $("#loginForm").delegate(".virtualKeyboardField", "click.xpto", BindKeyboards);
  }
  function UnBindKeyboards() {
    $("#loginForm").undelegate(".virtualKeyboardField", "click.xpto", BindKeyboards);
  }
  function BindKeyboards() {
    // alert(event.currentTarget.id);
    //alert("xpto");
    if ($("#cb_showVKey").is(':checked')) {
      $("#loginUserName").keyboard({
        layout: 'qwerty',
        lockInput: true,
        preventPaste: true
      });
      $("#loginUserPassword").keyboard({
        layout: 'qwerty',
        lockInput: true,
        preventPaste: true
      });
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginForm").validate();
    BindKeyboards();
  });
</script>
```

Any help guys?

Answer (score 1):

That does what you need

```
var keys;
var key_init=function() {keys=$('#keyboard').keyboard().getkeyboard();};

key_init();
$('#switch_kbd').change(
  function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')==='checked') { key_init(); return;}
    keys.destroy();
  }
);
```

[sample](http://jsbin.com/ubajaq/2/)

I updated it's wiki, and also noted that it was pointed to [layout demo](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/layouts.html) which uses same solution.

from their [docs](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Methods):

> keyboard is the keyboard data object which you can also access using $('#keyboard').getkeyboard()
>
> Use keyboard.destroy()
>
> - This function completely removes the keyboard and events from the input.
> - This function is needed if you plan to change the keyboard layout when using the same input. See the [layout demo.](http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/layouts.html)

Comment: it works.
anyway... does the way i was trying make any sense?

Comment: idk, you asked how to I answered